# Include and size local images from local directory into Xaringan (remark.js) presentation ... (using via Rstudio on mac)

Tags: xaringan, remarkjs

I want to include images/material from local directory into a Xaringan remark.js presentatio and size them. 
I'm doing this via Rmd/Rstudio on a mac. I want to be able to customise the size with a macro as suggested in [Yihui's docs](https://slides.yihui.name/xaringan/#34)

The suggested macros to size this do not work for me.

Adding the line:

```
.center[![trachoma](picsfigs/trachoma.jpg)]
```

works fine, but adding 
beforeInit: "macros.js"
and adding the macros to that file knitting yields a blank presentation

```
---
title: "A Cool Presentation"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    css: [default, metropolis, metropolis-fonts]
    seal: true
    self_contained: true
    yolo: false
    beforeInit: "macros.js"
    nature:
      autoplay: 30000
---

- Hello world 

---

--- 

# new slide??

This works:


.center[![trachoma](picsfigs/trachoma.jpg)]

---

But this does not work:

.center[![:scale 50%](picsfigs/trachoma.jpg)]

Nor this

.center[![trachoma][:scale 50%](picsfigs/trachoma.jpg)]

one more slide

---
```

macros.js file:

```
remark.macros.scale = function (percentage) {
  var url = this;
  return '<img src="' + url + '" style="width: ' + percentage + '" />';
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put `beforeInit: "macros.js"` under `nature` as below.

```
---
title: "A Cool Presentation"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    css: [default, metropolis, metropolis-fonts]
    seal: true
    self_contained: true
    yolo: false
    nature:
      autoplay: 30000
      beforeInit: "macros.js"
---
```